# Applescripts: Sending keystrokes to a java program invoked through a shell script

Tags: shell, jar, applescript, executable-jar

Good morning, afternoon, and evening:

I have this script here that calls a little shell script to run a jar, waits 1 second, and then sends a keystroke to that jar in order to test whether or not sending a keystroke works. For some reason, the input doesn't show up in the jar's input fields within the GUI, which is the problem.

My thought process is that the applescript should invoke the shell script, wait for it to fully load, and then be able to simply send input to the frontmost application...but I have experienced complications.

I'm thinking it miiight be possible that System Events is having a hard time finding the right application to send keys to since  it is called via shell script within the applscript. Or perhaps it is possible that the jar has some sort of scripting protection or input scrubbing? Or maybe I just a noob at making scripts? Here is the script so far:

```
do shell script "java -jar 
~/Downloads/ExampleJavaProgram.jar"
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a" --test value--
```

I tried calling the application by PID and ran into similar trouble

Comment: Does the java program and the input field have focus when it's run in this manner ?  Have you tried increasing the delay ?  You could also try inserting `activate application "<name of java program>"` immediately before you invoke _System Events_.

Comment: Ah, a pertinent piece of information that is vital to diagnosing the problem.  The answer is _Yes_, that is very possible, indeed.  In fact, I'd put money on it.

Comment: I tried delay {2, 3, 4, 5, and 10} with no success. The java program and input field does have the focus (blinking cursor in text field). Is is possible that the shell script never terminates, so the keystrokes are never called? I ask because in order to stop the script I first have to close the java program, otherwise the script simply continues to be active without stopping.

Apparently I can edit comments. TIL

Comment: Ah ok thank you for the troubleshooting! Very helpful. I will seek a workaround.

Comment: The solution is probably to stick an ampersand onto the end of your shell command, i.e. `do shell script "java -jar ~/Downloads/ExampleJavaProgram.jar &"`

Comment: Background execution may work for some solutions but not mine since I need the application to be in the foreground. I think I need to find a way to invoke the jar in some way other than a shell script, so I'm doing some Googling :) 

Again, thanks for the help. In talking it through it became more clear what the issue was

Comment: No problem.  I don't have much experience with Java executables, but I **believe** _Finder_ can run them, right ?  So my last suggestion of the day is replacing your `do shell script` with `tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/Users/%you%/Downloads/ExampleJavaProgram.jar"` (you can't use a `~` with _Finder_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking the problem out with the kind user in the comments above, I decided to simply activate a second Applescript to take care of the keystrokes issue. So now I have 1 script running the jar and another to input the keys running on a delay. It is simple and it gets the job done.